# Groovy script - compare SOAPUI project property

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have SOAPUI project with more suites. One for "independent functions", Test_environment_1, Test_environment_2, etc.

I use SOAPUI Project property for store the environment URLs.

Now I need to make simple Groovy script with condition, which should read the Project property: "environment" Then decide if condition is true and then write a message in log output.

Custom Project property is "*environment*" and the value is "*test1*"

**Groovy:**

```
def projectProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("environment")
def environment
log.info "Environment: " + projectProperty
if (projectProperty == 'test1') 
     log.info "true"
```

Actual log output:

```
INFO:Environment: test1
```

In log output should be:

```
INFO:Environment: test1
INFO:true
```

Does anybody know how to make conditions work with values from Project Property?

Comment: When I copy/paste your code into a Groovy Script teststep in my free version of SoapUI, I get the output you expect.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally added a whitespace after the value in the properties?

Comment: Try changing your first line to def projectProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("environment").trim()

Comment: @Steen Thanks, it's working now